# Index was outside the bounds of the array - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
char[] str1 = new char[1000];
int k = 9, n = 0;
for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str1[n] = str[j];
    n++;
}
str1[n] = '\0';
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar me sale un error aquí:

> str1[n] = '\0';

que dice:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Por qué me sale ese error, en el código antes de ejecutar no me salen errores, pero al momento de correr el programa me sale error ahí, agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: @Lobos La longitud varía, el usuario es quien introduce un valor, ej: "abcABC1"

Comment: @Lobos En el caso de que `str`  sea de longitud menor de 9 siempre ocurriría un error en la primera iteración  del lazo `for` en la linea `str1[n] = str[j]`; pues el `index` `j` estaría fuera del rango, tal como está planteado el bloque `for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--)` se realizarían iteraciones desde `j=8` hasta `j=0`, por ejemplo para longitud 8, `index` `j` estaría entre 0 y 7, en estos casos siempre saltaría el error, _La respuesta de Leandro Tuttini resuelve este error._. **Pero en la linea `str1[n] = '\0';` contrario a lo que plantea la pregunta, nunca saltaría un error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una cadena de caracteres variable no deberias definir un array de char de 1000, eso no es correcto. Menos aun si despues la variable `k` la defines con el valor 9 fijo, cuando no lo es realmente

Si vas hacer codigo que dependa del input de la cadena aplica esa misma logica

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cadena:");
        string cadena = Console.ReadLine();
        
        char[] str = cadena.ToCharArray();
        
        char[] str1 = new char[str.Length + 1];
        int k = str.Length;
        int n = 0;
        
        for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            str1[n] = str[j];
            n++;
        }
        str1[n] = '\0';
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result= {0}", new string(str1));
    }
}
```

La idea es que tomes als dimensiones de la cadena original para definir las dimeniones de los array que vas a recorrer